# Cannot pickup an object twice (Use child of a second time)

Tags: animation, objects

I am having trouble picking up and releasing an object twice with Child Of constraint.

I can do a full cycle of pick up, lift the object, drop and put the arm that picked it up to rest.
Second time I try to pick it up and raise influence to 1, the offset applies and the object is misplaced.
If I apply "set inverse" it is fixed but it messes up the original pickup cycle.

Any ideas?

**NEW EDIT:** File can be found here:

[image]

Comment: Hey there, you can share your file using [Blender-Exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/), you will need to copy the questions address, since it's only meant to be used for questions or answers.

Comment: Thank you, Xylvier, I just uploaded the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking over the file i saw that you used **one** "Child Of" constraint, animated it with **0** influence until one frame before the time it needs to be activated, then activated it with **1** influence to pick it up and later used the reverse, keyed **1** influence and one frame later the **0** influence to drop the "Child Of", so it could be picked up later again.

All that was working fine, a few too many keyframes were used before the actual action, as you only need to use two keys for activating and deactivating.
 *If not needed, i would suggest to remove unneeded keys though.*
Those two times would have been enough, but that did not cause the problem.

What is important though, is that you can not use the same "Child Of" Constraint for a second time without it keeping the relative position after it was used once. (all my tests either caused the later or previous positions relative to the parent to be messed up.
 Sure you can use the **Set Inverse** or **Clear Inverse** buttons, but they pretty much do mess up any previous usage or an already keyed later usage.

**Solution:**
Use **one** "Child Of" constraint per **pick up -> manipulating -> drop** phase.

Here a little visual helper:
[image]
I extended the animation a bit, to showcase a second pickup.

Also here the file to examine, as it may help to understand looking at the details:
[image]

While i believe it is better to know how it works, i do not want to withhold the fact that there is an addon called [Dynamic Parent](https://blenderartists.org/t/wip-dynamic-parent-addon/577468/89), that *kinda* makes it easier to attach items to different parents. Beware though that if you use it, it can become very fast messy with many "Child Of" constraints. So understanding what happens first helps a lot.

Happy Blending

Comment: Super clear answer Xylvier. Really appreciated! I'll study the file you shared for sure and try to clean up the unnecessary keys to learn further.